# Get Interactions REST API method not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, fuel

I'm trying to use the documented GET [/interactions/rest method](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/rest.html) to identify available methods from the Interaction Service Discovery Document, but it doesn't seem to work. I get the error:

```
{"message":"Must provide a valid ID or Key parameter","errorcode":10005,"documentation":""}
```

I shouldn't need to provide an ID or Key, but if I do, then I get a 404 error.

Can someone confirm if this method actually works?

Comment: Could you please post the entire routes with parameters, obfuscating as necessary?

Comment: Hi Timothy, sure refer to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/eliotharper/2b5ae9f0655ebf36dc8b)

Comment: Hey @EliotHarper did you manage to figure out how to retrieve the interactions collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
headers: 
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Type: application/json
GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/rest
```

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks this works for me too. It looks like the documentation has been updated to include the correct route as the route documented previously didn't work. What's interesting is that the method reveals upcoming features in the next release related to Journey Maps. Also, there are several other helpful methods such as `getWaitStatistics` and `searchTraceEvents` that aren't yet documented. I'll have a play!

Answer (score 0):

```
 "getInteraction": {<br/>
             "path": "interactions/{id}",<br/>
            "httpMethod": "get",<br/>
            "description": "Retrieve an interaction.",<br/>
            "parameters": {}<br/>
        }
```

This is how the method should look like. More details here :https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/getInteractionById.html

Comment: Yes, but that's for getting an interaction by ID. I know that works. I'm referring to the method to [retrieve all methods](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/rest.html).